# How to have Text overlay Image on Banner

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a banner div element that has a picture overlapping it. I want to have my text not be overlapped by the image, but am having issues.

Example of the problem:

[image: Image overlapping text]

Here is what my html looks like:

```css
.header-banner-container {
  background: #221E1F;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11vh;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-logo {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 3px;
  height: 89px;
  width: 92px;
}

.banner-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="header-logo img" src="../../../assets/CatPicture.png">
<div class="container-fluid header-banner-container">
  <span class="banner-text">There is a cat above me</span>
</div>
```

My questions are:

1. Should the image be in the container-fluid div, as a best practice? Or is having it outside the banner as I do currently, correct?
2. How can I get the text to not be overlapped by the image?

Thanks for any advice for the questions, and any other advice you may have!

Comment: You could put logo and text into the same div and apply your class header-logo to it, so it’s grouped in the same layer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a logo or something that belongs in the header, then yes, you should keep the image in the header container, and the text too. You could resolve the issue of the overlapping text easily by simply increasing the vh of the container div and moving the banner-text top attribute down slightly this way.

However, if the case is other than above, and you want to keep the text in that position but make it visible, then you could move the banner text out of the text and position it absolutely from the top. As-is, adjusting the z-index to 0 (e.g.) while it is still within the container div would have no effect as the container div's z-index of -1 would take precedence, and if adjusted higher, would overlap the image also.

Hope this helps

```css
.header-banner-container {
  background: #221E1F;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11vh;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-logo {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 3px;
  height: 89px;
  width: 92px;
}

.banner-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<img class="header-logo img" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png">
<div class="container-fluid header-banner-container">

</div>
<span class="banner-text">There is a cat above me</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Example</title>    
<style>
.header-banner-container {
  background: #221E1F;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11vh;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.header-logo {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 3px;
  height: 89px;
  width: 92px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.banner-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 49px;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 50px;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px black;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img class="header-logo img" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/geometric-background_23-2148064464.jpg">
      <div class="container-fluid header-banner-container">      
      </div>
      <span class="banner-text">There is a cat above me</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have attached the code as per you wanted. you can change the CSS property in overlap class. as per you need.

Thanks.